# Converting image to a 3D CAD relief model based on pixel brightness or colour

Tags: 3d, autocad, cad, solidworks

I'm looking for some kind of way to convert an image into a 3D CAD relief model based on the brightness or colour of each pixel. For example if you have an image that is a gradient from black to white the resulting CAD would be a rectangular ramp or wedge shape.

I really don't have much experience with code driven CAD so any help is much appreciated.
I own a copy of solidworks and have access to autocad as well and I'm willing to learn any other free CAD options.

Comment: Do you have a kind of idea how you can evaluate the 3rd dimension (that is lacking on your image)? Do you suppose that their is only one source of light, or that the object has only one color?

Comment: You should look into bivariate interpolation/approximation literatures.

Answer (score 0):

I approached this issue by using solidworks macros with VBA. Each pixel is extruded as a square prism based on its brightness determined by its rgb values. The code is still very buggy but refer to this issue if you want code to help achieve this very obscure problem I have set for myself :)
[Some extrusions in loop in solidworks VBA don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567191/some-extrusions-in-loop-in-solidworks-vba-dont-work)